# how can I use display filters (diameter or sip) in tshark "capture filter"?

Tags: wireshark, reduce, tshark

I am getting pcap size of 5GB, so I tried to reduce the size of my pcap by applying capture filter. tshark "CAPTURE FILTER" doesn't accept any 3gpp protocol as its syntax, so I captured pcap then on top of that I applied display filter then my pcap size got reduced. Here my concern is, it is a time taken process.

Basically I would like to reduce my pcap while capturing it.

How can I reduce pcap size using capture filter?

```
capture filter I used :tshark   -i 1   -w /tmp/manual.pcap
Display filter I used :tshark -r  /tmp/manual.pcap -Y "(diameter &&! diameter.cmd.code==280) or sip.from.addr contains <msisdn>" -w /tmp/reduced3.pcap
```

I wanted to use the display filter while capturing pcap.

Answer (score 1):

Capture filters are evaluated by a "virtual machine" that, for live capturing, usually runs in the OS kernel; it has a "machine language" that's limited in order to prevent dangerous code from being loaded into the kernel.

Wireshark/TShark display filters are evaluated by the Wireshark/TShark dissection mechanism, so it has a lot more power.  Thus, arbitrary display filters can't necessarily be turned into capture filters.

In this *particular* case, what you could do would be to limit the capture to packets sent on or received by the default Diameter or SIP ports, such as

```
tcp port 3868 or udp portrange 5060-5061
```

That won't capture *only* the packets you care about, but it will probably avoid capturing non-Diameter and non-SIP ports.

If Diameter packets *aren't* on TCP port 3868, or SIP packets *aren't* on UDP ports 5060 or 5061, they won't be captured, however.

Comment: Did you mean arbitrary display filters can't necessarily be turned into *capture filters*?

Comment: "Did you mean arbitrary display filters can't necessarily be turned into capture filters?"  Yes - fixed.